# How to play music with the front speaker on Android

Tags: java, android

i have this code for detect if the smartphone plays music

```
myButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Evento click
               if(mAudio.isMusicActive())
               {
                   //Code Here
               }

            }
        });
```

i need to play music on the internal speaker(is used to talk on the phone) is possible?